# Custom Materials With Three.ShaderMaterial in A-Frame

Tags: three.js, aframe

I'm trying to use [`THREE.ShaderMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/api/materials/ShaderMaterial.html) to make a [custom material](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/components/material.html#register-a-custom-material) in A-Frame. Apparently A-Frame doesn't compile the shader if it's not coming through the registerShader API. The wireframe property takes effect but the shader doesn't work. In particular, I wanted to have wireframe rendering besides my shader which simply changes the color of vertices based on their distance from a particular point (`pos`). Is there any way to either change this code to force A-Frame to compile the shader or to use the shader API and still achieve the wireframe and other properties of [`THREE.ShaderMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/api/materials/ShaderMaterial.html).

```
AFRAME.registerShader('shellmaterial', {

schema: {
    color: {default: {value: new THREE.Color(255, 255, 255)}},
    pos: {default: {value: {x: 132.89, y: 50.64, z: -106.52}}}
},

init: function (data) {
    let uniformsObj = {color: data.color, pos: data.pos};

    this.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        wireframe: true,
        shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
        uniforms: uniformsObj,
        vertexShader: this.vertexShader,
        fragmentShader: this.fragmentShader
    });
},


update: function (data) {
    let uniformsObj = {color: data.color, pos: data.pos};

    this.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        wireframe: true,
        shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
        uniforms: uniformsObj,
        vertexShader: this.vertexShader,
        fragmentShader: this.fragmentShader
    });
},

vertexShader:

 `
   uniform vec3 color;
   uniform vec3 pos;
   varying vec3 vColor;
   varying float dist;

   void main(){
        dist = distance(position,pos);        
            if (dist<500.0){
                vColor = vec3(1.0,dist/500.0,dist/500.0);
            }
            else{
                vColor = vec3(1.0);
            }
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );}
    `,

fragmentShader: `
uniform vec3 color;
varying vec3 vColor;

void main(){
  gl_FragColor = vec4( color*vColor, 1.0 );
}
`
});
```

Comment: Try passing in `vertexShader`/`fragmentShader` inline or through a separate variable? Maybe that will help tell A-Frame to use the `ShaderMaterial` you've created.

Comment: Also not sure how well `wireframe` composes with custom shaders.

Answer (score 0):

You could build the wireframe shader into your custom shader or try two renders of the same object with a different material and composite them on top of each other?  Either should work, rendering twice means more draw calls but if you don't care about frame rate too much it might be easier than combining the two shaders depending upon your knowledge of shader code.